Connection between Derivatives and Regression?
I have often seen mention of a relationship between derivatives and linear regression but never quite understood what was being referred to. I tried to derive it myself.
Consider the linear regression model:
$$ Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + ... + \beta_kX_k + \epsilon $$
Where:

$Y$ is the dependent variable
$X_1, X_2, ..., X_k$ are independent variables
$\beta_0, \beta_1, ..., \beta_k$ are regression coefficients
$\epsilon$ is the error term

I tried to do this manipulation:
$$ Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + ... + \beta_kX_k + \epsilon $$
Take the expectation of both sides, conditional on X:
$$ E(Y|X) = E(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + ... + \beta_kX_k + \epsilon|X) $$
Use the linearity of expectation:
$$ E(Y|X) = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + ... + \beta_kX_k + E(\epsilon|X) $$
Assume $E(\epsilon|X) = 0$ (a key assumption in OLS):
$$ E(Y|X) = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + ... + \beta_kX_k $$
Here is where I think we can take the partial derivative with respect to $X_j$:
$$ \frac{\partial E(Y|X)}{\partial X_j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial X_j}(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + ... + \beta_kX_k) $$
Apply the rules of differentiation:
$$ \frac{\partial E(Y|X)}{\partial X_j} = 0 + 0 + ... + \beta_j + ... + 0 = \beta_j $$
Thus:
$$ \beta_j = \frac{\partial E(Y|X)}{\partial X_j} $$
I think this shows that $\beta_j$ represents the change in the expected value of Y associated with a one-unit change in $X_j$, holding all other variables constant?

Obviously. $\phantom.$
